# Function returns right value and then adds null

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
Pell[0] = 0;
Pell[1] = 1;
Pell[n_] := Pell[n] = If[n >= 1,
    Return[2*Pell[n - 1] + Pell[n - 2]];
    ];
```

This is my n-th pell's number finding function. It works fine, but it always returns value+null. For example when I call function for number 5, it returns `99 Null`. I want return value to be only `99`

Comment: **Pell[n - 2]** must be giving you Pell[-1] which is NULL and it seems **+** here works as concatenation

Comment: This works just fine. Restart your kernel to make sure you dont have some old definition floating around.  The `Return` is superfluous by the way, just do `Pell[n_] := Pell[n] = If[n >= 1, 2*Pell[n - 1] + Pell[n - 2]]`  (`Return` is almost never used in mathematica )

Comment: @agentp Here the removal of `Return[]` is good idea; but on "is almost never used" I disagree. I guess that is a question of programming style, but apart from being an important part of flow control it very often increases readability (at least for me) of code even in short functions....but ok, not in the present case.